# The Weyl group and eigenspaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $V$ be a representation of the Weyl group. For any reflection $\sigma_{\alpha}$ (where $\alpha$ is a root), we know that $V$ has two eigenspaces with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. The $-1$-eigenspace is one dimensional.

I came across a statement like this in unapologetic mathematician but was a little confused. To me it seems like the $1$-eigenspace has to be one dimensional. So, for example, if $\sigma_{\alpha}$ is a reflection across a certain line, then everything outside the line perpendicular to $\sigma_{\alpha}$ would belong to the $-1$-eigenspace (I'm not sure how a single element can generate this space). But *only* the elements on the reflection line would belong to the $1$-eigenspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a reflection representation, $\sigma_\alpha$ acts as the reflection at a *hyperplane*, which means that the hyperplane is fixed and the vectors orthogonal to it get multiplied by $-1$. Hence the eigenspace of $-1$ is indeed $1$-dimensional.

However, in an *arbitrary* representation of the Weyl group, abstract reflections do not necessarily act as reflections at hyperplanes, so one should probably add this assumption in your context.